# Dynamic Filtering on LibreOffice Base Reports

Tags: libreoffice-base

Is it possible to do a Dynamic Filtering on LibreOffice Base Reports?

Comment: What is dynamic filtering ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you are using the default database type. Build the table on a query with parameters. That is, if you have a table T and want to filter on a field A in the table, set up a query like this: `SELECT * FROM T WHERE A=:parameter`

You will be prompted for the parameter when you open the table. Only matching records are printed.

You can even include the parameter value in the table, at least when using the libreoffice report builder extension

Answer (score 1):

could be possible to use a dummy like

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE A:=parameter (OR A=anyregister IF they pres RETURN without write anything)
```

The idea is ask a lot of parameters to the user, and the user decide what parameters must be used